# requests_html scroll all the way down until finished youtube

Tags: python, python-requests

this is my current code for extracting youtube video but its able to only get 20 videos no more but i want to get much more then this .

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
#create the session
session = HTMLSession()

#define our URL
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cute+dogs&sp=EggIBRABGAEwAQ%253D%253D'

#use the session to get the data
r = session.get(url)

#Render the page, up the number on scrolldown to page down multiple times on a page
r.html.render(sleep=5,timeout = 30, keep_page=True, scrolldown=40)

info = re.findall('"publishedTimeText":{"simpleText":"(.*?)"publishedTimeText":{"simpleText":"',r.text)

info2 = re.findall('{"openMiniplayer":true,"videoId":"(.*?){"openMiniplayer":true,"videoId":"',r.text)
print(len(info2))

for x in range(0,40):
    #views = re.findall('"viewCountText":{"simpleText":"(.*?)"},',info2[x])
    time = re.findall('"text":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"(.*?)"}},"simpleText":"',info2[x])

    url = str(info2[x])[0:11]

    print(url,time)
    


session.close()
#print(info[0])

#output dict {time ,  title_of video , link}
```

my goal for this project is to get all the videos from the link given"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cute+dogs&sp=EggIBRABGAEwAQ%253D%253D" also no YouTube API only requests

---

***this is the updated code know i need to combine time,link and title all in a dict***

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

#create the session
session = HTMLSession()

#define our URL
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cute+dogs&sp=EggIBRABGAEwAQ%253D%253D'

#use the session to get the data
r = session.get(url)

#Render the page, up the number on scrolldown to page down multiple times on a page
r.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=10,timeout = 30)

#take the rendered html and find the element that we are interested in
videos = r.html.find('#overlays')


print(videos)

for x in videos:
    print(x.text)

'''
#loop through those elements extracting the text and link
for item in videos:
    video = {
        'title': item.text,
        'link': item.absolute_links
    }
    print(video,item)
'''
```

Comment: you can use python beautifulsoup to scrap the data you want from the html

Comment: yeah i know i could use bs4 but im really bad at it also i found a different way

Comment: Is the problem here that you want to keep grabbing more videos the way you can as a user by continuing to scroll the page?

Comment: can you provide the output of the `print(videos)`